# Difference between map and subscribe on Mono\Flux?

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-webflux

Am I right to assume that "map" could essentially be a "subscribe" with a return type . They both seem to get called asynchronously when the promise gets resolved ?

For example , if I dispatch a list of 3 Async calls concurrently, would applying the map operation in manner below be blocking ?

```
 Flux.merge(albums.stream().map(album -> {

        Mono<CoverResponse> responseMono  = clientRequestHandler.makeAsyncCall()

           //2.call and handler for async call
           return responseMono
                   .map(response -> processResponse());

       }).collect(Collectors.toList())).then(Mono.just(monoResponse));
```

In the above snippet, is each map operation going to be blocking? If say, the first call takes 5 ms to to return and every other call takes 2 ms to return , are we going to wait 3ms+2ms+2m = 7ms for the enitre operation ? or just 3ms since once the first call gets resolved , the 2ms calls are already resolved by then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, nothing will happen until someone subscribes. Subscribe is the last thing in the chain, that will trigger the start of all the events.

Second of all you need to understand the difference of running something in parallell vs running something non-blocking.

to resolve your first map, it needs to make the rest call, then with the response it needs to do your second map. These two wont be run in parallell.

Your `responseMono.map` can't be run until `Mono<Response> responseMono` actually has something in it. Think of it as a `Promise` that will signal the application when it has been resolved.

Or you can think of it as a chain of callbacks.

So in your example you are doing a `clientRequestHandler.makeAsyncCall()` but you are returning a `Mono<CoverResponse>` the next part the `responseMono.map` wont trigger, until there is a `CoverResponse` in the mono. So your "async" call, is probably async, but still adheres to list order since its all in a sequential stream.

But `map` is a mapping function. It takes something out of the box, performs a computation on something in the box and then returns the new value or type.

What makes reactive better than other options is that when you do your `side effect` the remote call somewhere that takes time, the thread that is processing this wont hang around and wait for the external request to finish, it will start doing other things, like processing other requests.

Then when the `Mono<Response>` signals the system that there is "something in the box" a response, then the same thread or any other available thread will keep on processing the request.

Comment: This was somewhat illuminating thank you . I guess the gist of what you said is that even though for map to proceed with processing of a response , that promise needs to have been resolved (responseMono must then have something in it), but by the virtue of this being reactive , the processing thread won't sit idle waiting for it to get resolved , it will immediately fire the next http call . The part I don't understand is that if the former is the case , why would you say the calls are not async . After all we are not waiting on a http call to return before making another call.

Comment: well async is a word that doesn't really get used in a reactive world. You don't mix and match reactive and `@async`. And the word `Promise` is not really used either even though `Promise` is a `CompletableFuture` which is the underlying technology for `Mono` and `Flux`. Why i said its not really async is because its called in a stream, that still adheres to list order, but my phrasing was bad, its run `async`, but `sequentially`

Comment: we can talk more in the chat if you want to https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195968/webflux

Comment: I really wish we could but apparently you need to have made a 20 reputation score to join I just recently created a profile.